# Making multiple .append calls vs storing local variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been making a page that displays some recent news from the Guardian (using a jQuery .ajax call).
There's a section with 10 recent news articles and I'm making each article using  .append (+ the data from the api call) inside a for loop.

The code is starting to get unreadable though having many items inside one .append call so I was thinking about a couple of different ways to clean it up.

My question is, in this situation what would be best practice? Making local variables for each part of the news item (title, thumbnail etc):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            var content = json.response.results[i];

            var title =      '<h3 class="news-item-font">' + content.webTitle + '</h3>';
            var thumbnail =  '<div class="inner thumbnail">' + content.fields.main + </div>;
            var date =       '<h4 class="date">' + content.webPublicationDate + '</h4>';
            var description = '<p>' + content.fields.standfirst + '</p><p class="push-top push-bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>';

            $('.news').append(
                '<div class="news-item">'
                    + title
                    + thumbnail
                    + date
                    + description
                + '</div>');
        }
```

Or making multiple .append calls, so something more like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var content = json.response.results[i];

    $('.news').append('<div class="news-item">');
    $('.news').append('<h3 class="news-item-font">'  +  content.webTitle + '</h3>');
    $('.news').append('<div class="inner thumbnail">' + content.fields.main + '</div>');
    $('.news').append('<h4 class="date">'            +  content.webPublicationDate + '</h4>';);
    $('.news').append('<p>'                          +  content.fields.standfirst + '</p>');
    $('.news').append('<p class="push-top push-bottom"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>');
}
```

Maybe this isn't such an issue with 10 news articles but if I were to increase the number could there be other problems?

I'm a javascript noob so go easy on me! :) Any help or suggestions would be great! Thanks

Comment: Your second solution is not valid as it won't deliver the same html structure as the first one

Comment: Do not modify DOM inside a loop. It is expensive. Maintain a temporary variable, and append the result outside of the loop instead.

Comment: If you are worried about readability you can look at a templating engine to generate the html like [jsrender](https://github.com/borismoore/jsrender) or [underscore template](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

Comment: Other than that since it is primarily an opinion based question, IMHO it is not a good fit for SO, you can look at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as an alternate

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions